# Grails CreateCriteria Select disitinct over from Table

Tags: grails, hibernate-criteria, grails-2.5

I use grails 2.5.6 with IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4

I have a problem with my criteria

```
Book.createCriteria().listDistinct{
    person{
        address{
            eq("id", 5)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write a projection of the Book

Normal criteria create a SQL with:
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM book AS b INNER JOIN ....
But I need a SQL like this:
SELECT DISTINCT b.* FROM book AS b

How can I realize this projection in the createCriteria?
Or should I use a subselect with criteria?

(I dont want to use HQL)

Thanks, Marvin

My Classes:

```
class Book{
    //other stuff
    static hasMany = [person: Person]
}

class Person{
    //other stuff
    static hasMany=[address: Address]
}

class Address{
    //other stuff
}
```

Comment: I see you are using Querying Associations.  In order to help you could you tell me the associations among book, person, address.

Comment: You can not perform a grails create criteria on multiple domain, either you should have a association among domain like has many, has one belongs to etc. or you need to perform such join query using HQL.

Comment: HIbernate SQL is the way to go for cross table queries.